# Communities Username-Password Authentication Flow

Tags: community, oauth2, authentication

Is it possible to log a Communities user in via the Username-Password Auth Flow? 
With normal users you can call the `http://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` and passing the username, password, client id, client secret and grant type you can get an access token back. 
So would the communities version of this url be `https://<MySandbox>.cs14.force.com/<CommunityName>/services/oauth2/token`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to change the base URL to make it working. Here is a sample URL for you.

```
https://mysite.secure.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
```

The authorization service will recognize the custom hostname and further redirect the user to the Site login page, assuming the user is not yet authenticated. Note – if your site uses a path as well as the site domain, for example, https://mysite.secure.force.com/mypath, you will need to include that path in the authorization URL:

```
https://mysite.secure.force.com/mypath/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
```

[OAuth for Portal Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html)

Comment: This is what I am currently using, but the redirect is not the desired result. I was hoping to just get an access token like you can for normal users, and then use that token in subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

Oauth Username-Password flow does not support community user.

[SF docs:](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) Experience Cloud sites don’t support the OAuth 2.0 username-password flow

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Can you share any references or documentation to improve this asnwer?